# Как в notepad заменить все одинаковые фразы, на разные поочерёдно?

Tags: json, регулярные-выражения, notepad++, редактор-текста, замена-текста

Нужно заменить фразу, в конструкциях, на любые другие, с помощью регулярного выражения.
Я знаю как заменить несколько фраз: в найти - (123)|(321)|(567), в заменить (?{1}одиндватри)(?{2}тридваодин)(?{3}пятьшестьсемь). А как заменить первый найденный 123 на одиндватри, потом второй 123, на тридваодин, и так далее
Явно что-то делаю не так.
Нужно для быстрого форматирования json.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала явно не так задан вопрос. Он должен быть ясен и понятен не только автору, но и другим людям. Что надо-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик нужно заменить фразу, в конструкциях, на любые другие, с помощью регулярного выражения. Я знаю как заменить несколько фраз: в найти - (123)|(321)|(567), в заменить (?{1}одиндватри)(?{2}тридваодин)(?{3}пятьшестьсемь). А как заменить первый найденный 123 на одиндватри, потом второй 123, на тридваодин, и так далее.

Comment: Явно не с помощью текстового редактора. Используйте любой язык программирования.